# Is self signed certificate better in this case?

Tags: java, c#, ssl, certificate

I have a server application that talks to an integration application via HTTP Post and I want to encrypt that line of communication.
Both application may be in the same server machine or on different machines.
Both of them are winform applications so we are not talking about IIS or web site here at all.

I have control over both ends, meaning only the integration software uses this SSL certificate issued by the server and no other parties involved.

By researching I came up with the following cons/pro when I purchase VeriSign certificate instead of self sign.

**Pro:**

1. Better security (ranging 40 bits to 2048 bits encryption)
2. Trusted authority
3. Has feature that prevents phishing
4. High assurance certificate (domain & business name)
5. Suitable for ISO compliance purpose.

**Con:**

1. Cost, cost and more cost
2. A lot of features are web specific which is not applicable to me.
3. Useless if my server/client is not connected to the internet but in a LAN.  Since the certificate wont be able to properly verified by VeriSign.

In my case I already know & trust who is at the other end sending me the message (myself) and so I don't really feel the need to purchase a certificate.  Do you see any glaring counter argument or any feature specific found in VeriSign certificate that will persuade me doing otherwise? please let me know, I appreciate any inputs.

Comment: will it be public facing or just internal? If public facing, use a Trusted Authority, otherwise use Self-Signed. Trusted Authority certs are really just for browsers to automatically trust the cert.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's is public facing because both of these are considered server component.  Only admin allow to log into the machines that house these application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason for using a proper signed certificate for something like this. If you have access to both ends of the communication, you can just add the certificate as the only trusted certificate on the client as well. That way man in the middle attacks would require actually hacking the client's software, in which case having a signed certificate wouldn't be to much use either.

Put in other words. The main reason for paying for a signed certificate, is to establish the initial trust. But as you have access to the client's software, you can tell the client to only trust your self signed certificate.

If you do not have access to tell the clients what certificate to trust, buying a signed certificate might be a good idea.

Your point (1) about better security on the verified certificates is false. You can create your own certificate with as high an encryption as you want.